# Will there be a need for US national elections?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution

Suppose that the majority of the states decide to elect 1 person as their leader to replace the president.Then will there be a need for national US elections to vote for a president?What exactly will happen?Will there be national elections held even in that case?Who will be the head of the country?

Comment: Can you clarify ?

Comment: Related: 
[American civil war](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Civil_War), I think

Answer (score 2):

The US presidency operates strictly on four-year terms, which currently begin and end at noon on January 20th of every year that is one more than a multiple of four (for example, the current term began in 2021 and will end in 2025).  There is a national election for the presidency every four years in the last November of each presidential term.  As this fact is common knowledge, I suppose the question is

> Suppose that the majority of the states decide to elect 1 person as their leader to replace the president before the end of a four-year term.

It is certainly possible to remove a president before the expiration of the term of office.  The mechanism provided by the constitution is that of impeachment and conviction.  But any vacancy that may arise during a four-year term for any reason must be filled according to the constitution and any legislation that does not conflict with the constitution.  The constitution and the [presidential succession act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_Succession_Act) establish a "line of succession" from which a successor must be chosen essentially by algorithm.  If this [fairly long list of people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_Succession_Act#Table_of_statutory_successors) were to be exhausted without filling the office, it would be for congress to make further provisions, though its ability to do so without a president in office is questionable, because enacting legislation requires interacting with the president.

Thus, there is at present no provision for "early elections" as are common in parliamentary systems.  If "the people" came to the consensus that such an election were desirable, it would be possible to call one by [amending the constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amending_the_United_States_Constitution), which requires far more than a "majority of the states"; rather, it requires an amendment

- first to be approved by either

  - a vote of two thirds or more in both houses of congress, or
  - a constitutional convention called by congress in response to a request by two thirds or more of the state legislatures, and
- and subsequently to be approved by the legislatures of three fourths of the states.

Comment: For the question asked by a person unacquainted with the U.S. presidential election system, it is also worth noting that in presidential elections, the "weight" attached to each state's (monolithic?!? there are some impulses to revise this) preference is the number of electoral college votes, determined by number of representatives (+senators), which is roughly based on population. So, for example, if a majority of states consisted of low-population ones, they could not determine a president via the electoral college. Etc.